# The scrolldown function used in the webdriver searches from which part of the web page?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```
var elem = driver.FindElement(ObjectName);
          ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem);
```

My Question is from where this scrolldown operation searches the element??
From the top of the page every time or from the part of the element which it has focus presently??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it scroll to ur element by its location, that means if it is in top, it will scroll to top or if this in bottom, it will scroll to bottom by element locaiton.

Comment: Is it **automatically** scroll to the respective location irrespective of its location in the web page??? @noor